# Android: Show XMLs in a ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview

I would like to know if there is a possibility of showing some XML files which are in a specific folder, in a ListView. I don't want to show the info from those XML files, just the file names. For example if there are 3 files called "car.xml", "dog.xml" and "cat.xml" show in a ListView "Car, Dog , Cat.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "path");
    for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()){
        if (f.isFile()){
            if(f.getName().endsWith(".xml") || f.getName().endsWith(".XML")) {
                String filename = f.getName();
                String filenameArray[] = filename.split("\\.");
                String name = filenameArray[filenameArray.length-1];
                xmlFilesList.add(name);
            }
        }
    }
```